# Disable velocity.log with Apache velocity v2.0

Tags: java, slf4j, velocity, vtl, apache-velocity

I have recently migrated to Apache velocity v2.0 from 1.7.
I am calling my Java code from AWS Lambda function and hence I want to disable any velocity.log file that is created. In previous version we were using

ve.setProperty(Velocity.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS,NullLogChute.class.getName());

We are using @Slf4j to log the regular logs in the class.
Is there any way to disable the vtl logs?